# Taking out Specific Strings While Appending

Tags: python, string, list, append, strip

I am trying to translate some DNA sequences into protein sequences, but I am running into some DNA sequences with incomplete nucleic acids. I've gotten past them so far by using them to increase a counter every time they show up, but I would like to just take those sequences out of my list when appending them. The .strip() function only takes out the specific letters when they appear, but I would like to make the entire string be deleted from my list if an incomplete nucleic acid is found.
For reference, I'm taking about 100 of these sequences (see below) and translating them all. To sum it up, how do I delete one of the sequences when just 1 letter that is not ACTG is found?

```
AAAATAAAAACAACCAAAATGAAGGCAAGACTACTGGTCCTGTTATGTGCACTTGCAGCTACAGATGCAG
ACACAATATGTATAGGCTACCATGCGAACAACTCAACCGATACTGTTGACACAGTACTCGAAAAGAATGT
GACAGTGACACACTCTGTCAACCTACTCGAAGACAGCCACAACGGGAAATTATGTAGATTAAAAGGAATA
GCCCCACTACAATTGAGGAAATGTAACATTGCTGGATGGATCCTGGGAAACCCAGAATGCGAATCACTGC
TTTCAGAGAGATCATGGTCCTACATTGTTGAAACACCAAACTCTGAGAATGGAACATGTTACCCAGGAGA
TTTTACCAACTATGAGGAACTGAGGGAGCAATTGAGCTCTGTATCATCATTCGAAAGATTCGAAATATTC
CCCAAGGAAAGCTCATGGCCCAAACACAACACAACCAGAGGAGTAACGGCAGCATGCTCCCATGCGGGAA
AAAGCAGTTTTTACAGAAATTTGCTATGGCTGACGGAGAAGGATGGCTCATATCCGAATCTGAACAATTC
CTATGTGAACAAGAAAGGGAAAGAAGTCCTTGTACTATGGGGTGTTCATCACCCGTCCAACATAAAGGAT
CAACAGACCCTCTATCAGAAAGAAAATGCTTATGTCTCTGTAGTGTCTTCAAACTATAACAGGAGATTCA
CCCCGGAAATAGCAGAAAGACCCAAAGTAAGAGGTCAAGCAGGGAGGATGAACTATTACTGGACCTTGCT
AAAACCCGGAGACACAATAATGTTTGAGGCAAATGGAAATCTAATAGCGCCATGGTATGCTTTCGCACTA
AGTAGAGGCTTTGGGTCAGGCATCATCACCTCAAACGCATCGATGCATGAGTGTGACACGAAGTGTCAAA
CACCCCAGGGAGCTATAAACAGCAGTCTCCCTTTCCAGAATATCCACCCAGTCACAATAGGAGAGTGCCC
AAAATACGTCAGGAGTACCAAATTGAGGATGGTTACAGGACTACGGAACATCCCATCCATTCAATCCAGA
GGTCTATTTGGAGCCATTGCCGGTTTCATTGAAGGGGGATGGACTGGAATGATAGATGGATGGTATGGTT
ATCATCATCAGAATGAACAGGGATCAGGCTATGCTGCGGATCAAAAAAGCACACAAAATGCCATTAACGG
GATTACAAACAAGGTGAACTCTGTTATCGAGAAGATGAACACTCAATTCACTGCTGTGGGTAAAGAATTC
AACAACTTAGAAAAAAGGATGGAAAACTTAAACAAAAAAGTTGATGATGGATTTCTGGACATTTGGACAT
ATAATGCAGAATTGTTGATTCTACTGGAAAATGAAAGGACTCTGGATTTCCATGACTCAAATGTGAAGAA
TCTGTATGAAAAAGTTAAAAGCCAATTAAGGAATAATGCCAAAGAAATAGGAAACGGGTGTTTTGAGTTC
TACCACAAGTGTAACAATGAATGCATGGAAAGTGTAAAAAATGGAACTTATGATTATCCAAAATATTCAG
AAGAATCAAAGTTGAACAGGGAAAAAATAGATGGAGTGAAATTGGAATCAATGGGGGTCTATCAGATTCT
GGCGATCTACTCAACTGTCGCCAGTTCACTGGTGCTTCTAGTCTCCCTGGGGGCAATCAGCTTCTGGATG
TGTTCTAATGGGTCTTTGCAGTGCAGAATATGCATCTGAGATCAGAATTTCAGAAATATAAGGAAAAAAA
C
```

My code so far, as I previously mentioned, simply bypasses any errors by just tallying a counter.

```
protein = ''
protein_list = []
mutation = False
completed_HAseq = []
for sequence in selected_HAseqs:
    for i in range(0, len(sequence)-2, 3):
        codon = sequence[i:i+3]
        if codon not in FASTAdict:
            total_mutation_count += 1
        elif codon in FASTAdict:
            protein += FASTAdict[codon]
            completed_HAseq.append(sequence)
    protein_list.append(protein)
    protein = ''
```

I can't think of anything except to check each string for RYMKSWHBVDN, if it has it then I delete it. If not, I append it to the final list of translated sequences

Comment: Sample data showing what the sequences look like would be helpful here (especially for those who either never took biochemistry or took it many years ago and don't remember it).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for substrings and replace them

```
if "Subtring" in string:
     string.replace("Substring", "")
else:
     list.append(string)
```

Comment: Thats a great idea! However, one problem I ran into earlier was that there were multiple letters that do not belong in each sequence, resulting in my code running multiple times for each sequence. Since I'm reading a file, how do I skip past the rest of the sequence after the given substring is detected?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. I thought you were checking a sequence of strings for a substring. Where you would use above code or replace "string" with a list to check through. If I'm understaning wrong, could you rephrase the question ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, perhaps I didn't provide enough context. The sample sequence shown above in my question is what I am sorting through. I am appending about 100 of them, and I don't want to append any sequences that contain a select few letters. I'm confused on how to make the code provided above not run multiple times for each sequence, since each sequence may have multiple select letters. I want to just skip past the rest of the sequence and move on to the next.

Comment: Just to clarify.

You have 100 Strings in a List/Array that you want to check for a substring.
If they contain it you ignore them if not you append them to another array/list right?

Comment: Yeah! that's the rough gist of it.

Comment: for string in name_of_the_array:
       if "Substring" in string:
             pass
       else:
             other_sequence.append(string)

Comment: yea the formating died, just put the thing in a : for string in name_of_array loop, and replace string.replace("Substring, "") with pass

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what went wrong but it didn't seem to work. I ran the code and checked for errors and it returned that there were still characters in my code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Can you show me the check you did ? Im not entirely sure how Strings containing this substring could have bypassed the check other than case issues as the check is case sensative. To do it regardless of case use list.lower() to get it in lower case,